# Simulatenously Overriding and Overloading Methods in C++ Classes

Tags: c++

Consider the following snippet of code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    virtual ~A(){}
    virtual void saySomething() const
    {
        std::cout << "Hello from A" << std::endl;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual ~B(){}
    virtual void saySomething(const std::string& username) const
    {
        std::cout << "Greetings, " << username << "!" << std::endl;
        saySomething();
    }
};

class C : public B
{
public:
    virtual ~C(){}
    void saySomething() const
    {
        std::cout << "Hello from C" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    C* politeC = new C;
    B* politeB = dynamic_cast<B*>(politeC);
    politeB->saySomething("User");

    return 0;
}
```

Clang will give me a compiler error saying:

```
    $ clang inheritanceTest.cpp -o InheritanceTestinheritanceTest.cpp:20:9: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 1,
      have 0; did you mean 'A::saySomething'?
        saySomething();
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
        A::saySomething
        inheritanceTest.cpp:7:18: note: 'A::saySomething' declared here
        virtual void saySomething()
                 ^
        1 error generated.
```

However, if I do indeed say A::saySomething(), then the overriding of saySomething() in C is completely ignored. The program prints the output:

```
$ ./InheritanceTest 
Greetings, User!
Hello from A
```

The strange aspect of this is, if I just change the name of B::saySomething(const std::string& username) to B::greetUser(const std::string& username) then everything works as expected and I get:

```
$ ./InheritanceTest 
Greetings, User!
Hello from C
```

Does this mean that one cannot both overload and override methods in a C++ class hierarchy simultaneously? Why is this the case? Is there any logical reason why the compiler cannot unambiguously resolve the two overloaded function prototypes, and override the corresponding one as necessary?

Comment: You can add `override` after `saySomething()`, and then the compiler will check whether it in fact is an override.

Answer (score 2):

As a preface to this answer, what you are doing is rarely a good idea as those functions have different semantics and should not have the same name.

That said, the issue you are having as that the function names in the base classes are being covered by those in the derived classes. In order to fix this, you need to expose them like so:

```
class B : public A
{
public:
    using A::saySomething; //HERE expose the function
    virtual void saySomething(const std::string& username) const;
    {
        //the compiler now knows to look in the base class for this function
        saySomething(); 
    }
};

class C : public B
{
public:
    using B::saySomething; //and HERE
    void saySomething() const;
};
```

Now all versions of `saySomething` are available to call on instances of `C`. Furthermore, casting a `C*` to a `B*` will correctly call `C::saySomething` from `B::saySomething` because you aren't explicitly telling `B` which version to use, so it follows the virtual function correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
static_cast<A const*>(this)->saySomething();
```

You can also use a pointer-to-member-function:

```
(this->*(&A::saySomething))();
```

Comment: I am upvoting the answer because it is indeed useful. However, the question is more of a WHY this is happening rather than how to get around it. Hence I am not accepting this as an answer.

Comment: @MikeSeymour A::saySomething() does not give the same result as (this->*(&A::saySomething))(); It appears that in the former the function is resolved at compile time, but in the latter, the resolution, on account of using the function pointer indirection, results in resolution at runtime to C::saySomething()

Comment: @balajeerc: Sorry, I misread the question. You're right, but a few words of explanation might make a better answer.